# A tricky (or not) code

Tags: cipher

This code requires one half to solve the other. This shouldn't be too difficult.

Kpprvugdnoavwugzjdvwqswwcvoburnxvlqqrktduhvkkvkvobhltvvwkpgdpbydalylnovuawqoqrmiquusgonlpjgutrtvdxvlcpprvsguhhewcqflowaskqirpdrkqqgdpgvkkvkvconrphuwtlpjurcxvrertugfvluxuhnhuvkjwhuvkfqxngjdxhyukwvhplvrwwprtpconbcqfwjhpjqwvhpukgqivkgvrdehuzjbflfqvlfrvkcwvkkvkvihvwkqisthvwaoqqivqlylnogqflvkgug

Whyvhfpnrfnejnffgnoorqgjraglguerrgvzrfnppbeqvatgbebznauvfgbevnanaqculfvpvnafhrgbavhf

Yeah, this shouldn't take anybody more than ten minutes now that I look back on it. Enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to our site! As is, this question sadly not a very good fit, but don't let that discourage you. Please take a glance over [this informative posting](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) and see if you can edit your puzzle to be better received.

Comment: Thank you! This is my first time here, so I've been looking for something like that. The revised version of this will be here soon.

Answer (score 4):

The first half is:

> **VIGENERE CIPHER (key:CD) or GRONSFELD CIPHER (key:23)** I'm not really sure what to put as my solution phrase. This is my first time anyway. I will try to look for spelling errors but I am not perfect and I'm typing on a phone and this is all one string so autocorrect is useless. I guess I could have written it out normally and then gotten rid of the spaces. Why didn't I do that? This is getting pretty long so I will end it here.

The second half is:

> **CAESER CIPHER (ROT13)** Julius Caesar was stabbed twenty-three times according to Roman historian and physician Suetonius.

A Vigenere cipher is a multi-dimensional Caesar cipher. The offset value follows a key which repeats. To encode on a CD key, you alternate shifting each letter +2 and +3. To decode, it's the reverse: you alternate shifting each letter -2 and -3.

I have modified this Vigenere square as a decoding square:

> [image: vigenere decoding square]

Comment: How have you found out the Vigenère key, **CD** or **CDCD**?

Comment: Well, almost correct. I had used the Gronsfeld cipher, and 23 had been the key.

Comment: I added more information about how Vigenere ciphers work, and how they are decoded. My Python code always checks through all of the 2-letter keys first, so CD actually came up pretty quickly. I compare letter distribution to actual English distribution and if its close, the decoded string prints out. Brute force at its best (or worst)...

Comment: I edited my answer to include Gronsfeld 23, bringing it in line with the OP's specific method of encryption.

Comment: Any reason my answer hasn't yet been accepted? Am I missing something?

Comment: You forgot to add what the phrases give when the respective cipher is applied.